# Not able to delete httpOnly:true secure: true cookie using deleteAllCookies() in headless chrome in protractor in docker

Tags: docker, protractor, google-chrome-headless

Issue : not able to delete httpOnly:true , secure: true cookie using  browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() in headless chrome in protractor in docker.

**Able to do same in my local setup :  windows > protractor > chrome**

Setup : protractor 5.3.2 , chromedriverVersion: '2.37.544315 , chrome 'version' => '66.0.3359.117', platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) . Docker image : node:9-stretch.

Docker file options:

```
args "-v /tmp:/tmp --privileged  --net=host --shm-size=2gb"
```

Chrome options :

```
 args: ['no-sandbox','headless','disable-gpu','window-size=1366,768'],
```

Code sample :

```
    browser.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {       
        console.dir(cookies);
            browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            browser.sleep(5000).then(function (completed) {
                browser.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
                    console.dir(cookies);
                           });
    });
});
```

Comment: For what reason do you need to delete cookies inside a Docker?

Comment: Thanks for asking , was expecting that . Original problem started with logout failure in our application using automation . On clicking logout button  , a pop up appears with logout url (anchor element with href) , On clicking that element , logout happens (i.e redirection to several urls through UAA and ultimately landing on login page again). Behind the scene probably clearing auth cookie it seems or invalidating the session or cookie.  Last week clicking on the logout anchor element started failing with failure on clicking . protarctor session simply times out on click.

Comment: so initial thoughts were that click is failing , and i tried using browser.get('app_url/logout') instead of directly clicking on link . This too times out . I have verified that browser.get() works fine for change in hash or different url in docker setup.(earlier their was a issue logged  in chrome <65 ) . I also verified that click on link works fine , its not a click problem .

Comment: I feel that the issue is when app tries to clear cookies , the protractor session hangs their and times out while in docker setup . All this works absolutely fine in my local machine (windows).  While digging in this issue ,  i found out that cookies are not getting cleared in  docker for same protractor code , while in local they get cleared .

Comment: browser.restart () can be used to avoid logout and makes script run but i dont want to do that. I was trying to logout by clearing cookies  , that's where i observed this.

Comment: Hm, I have one idea. Could you show your protractor config file, please.

Comment: Can you be specific , since i am not able to post it here . here is start part:   directConnect: true,
    troubleshoot: true,
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

     
           args: ['no-sandbox','headless','disable-gpu','window-size=1366,768'],

Comment: onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();  Require other js here } ,

Answer (score 1):

add to your `capabilities` in `protractor.conf` file. It will force run each test in separate node js thread.

```
  capabilities: {
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1
  }
```

Comment: @krishan is it help you?

Comment: Thanks .I can try that but I don't understand how it's related to issue, shardTestFiles is for parallel execution of feature  files or may be for each scenario , I have not used it , so I don't know much.I have a feature file which contains mutiple  scenarioes dealing  with login and logout of different users  and parallel execution might be a temporary solution but that's not what I am looking at right now.but I will definitely give it a try to see how it works and update .

Comment: Let me know if the purpose of using shardTestFiles is something else other then providing temporary solution. Thanks

Comment: each test will run inside own process, so you will not need to delete cookie

Comment: dint work out , since it runs a feature file inside a thread , so all scenarios  inside that feature file share same thread

Comment: maybe will be better to split scenarios? one scenario = one file. Feature is a folder. It will help you when you will want turn on parallel execution. Also, as less file than it better maintenance.

Comment: we have many feature files itself having mutiple scenarios inside .If we have to make a file for each scenario , there will be hundreds of files , dont want that .

Comment: The other idea can be browser.restart after each scenario . Problem with this is , page elements are not recognized/found after that step , since i load page elements and js only in onPrepare() at start . I am facing problem with reinitializing the page objects again .  Any thoughts ?

Comment: I'm strongly recommend do not initialize any of page elements in `onPrepare()` block. Do not mess up configuration layer with test layer, etc. I really don't see any issue to separate scenarios, it will be folders in folders, but if it is your test architecture, so why not? For sure, it up to you. But where initialize the instances of Page Objects it is OOP thing. Do it directly in the place where you need it. I think you have some troubles with it. But try to decrease enthropy level ;)